# How to move files from current path to a specific folder named like or similar to the file being moved?

Tags: python, directory, directory-structure

My Folder Structure looks like this:

```
- 95000
- 95002
- 95009
- AR_95000.pdf
- AR_95002.pdf
- AR_95009.pdf
- BS_95000.pdf
- BS_95002.pdf
- BS_95009.pdf
```

*[Note 95000, 95002, 95009 are folders]*

---

My goal is to move files `AR_95000.pdf` and `BS_95000.pdf` to the folder named `95000`,
then `AR_95002.pdf` and `BS_95002.pdf` to the folder named `95002` and so on.

The PDFs are reports generated by system and thus I can not control the naming.

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49893501/python-moving-files-to-folder-based-on-filenames or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35510922/python-can-i-move-a-file-based-on-part-of-the-name-to-a-folder-with-that-name

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Using [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) this task becomes super easy:

```py
from pathlib import Path

root = Path("/path/to/your/root/dir")

for file in root.glob("*.pdf"):
    folder_name = file.stem.rpartition("_")[-1]
    file.rename(root / folder_name / file.name)
```

As you can see, one main advantage of `pathlib` over `os`/`shutil` (in this case) is the interface `Path` objects provide directly to `os`-like functions. This way the actual copying (`rename()`) is done directly as an instance method.

---

References:

- [`Path.glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.glob)
- [`Path.stem`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.stem)
- [`str.rpartition`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rpartition)
- [`Path.rename`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.rename)
- [path concatenation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#operators)

Comment: This worked like as you mentioned, its fast and all files moved inside respective folders. I  was fiddling with shutil but no avail and constantly getting errors...having said that if you get the time can you mention how above code works. I am getting some sence that you split the files by underscore[ _ ] and then what is next part of code `file.stem.rsplit("_", 1)[-1]`

Comment: @DrpRD if you are familiar with the [`split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) method, then [`rsplit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rsplit) basically does the same, but once you give it the extra `maxsplit` argument - the splits are counted from the right. This way because we only want the last part after `_` (assuming `AB_CD_9500` is also an option) we only split once from the right - `rsplit('_', 1)`. This returns `['AR', '95000']` and by indexing with `[-1]` we take the last element (`95000`)